# Read in file and print dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, file-io, key

Here is my input file:

```
Drew, Matthew J., s1058828
Howerth, Chloe E., s1002240
Karolewicz, Michael J., s0995867
Perzely, Connor J., s0958005
Tanenbaum, Roberto, s1124377
Guan, Tiffany, s1103462
Jaligama, Vishnu Praneeth, s1143667
Jin, Ailan, s1152308
```

I am new to Python and my task is to take roster files and get them into dictionaries and "for now" print the key: values. I feel like I'm close with this.

```
roster = {}
input_file = open("cs371598roster", "r")
whole_thing = input_file.read()
lines = whole_thing.split("\n")

for line in lines:
    last,first,ids = line.split(", ")

for i in range(len(last)):
    key = ids[i]
    val = first[i] + " " + last[i]
    roster[key] = val

print(roster)
```

Comment: Sorry, what is the expected outcome? Right now you are assigning variables `last, first, ids` for every line in lines, and only using the last one, because you reinitialize the variables for every line.

Comment: That looks like a CSV format file, so you should consider using the `csv` module to read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `with | as` and set the id to a value of the first and last names joined by a space. This works:

```
roster = {}
input_file = open("cs371598roster", "r")
with input_file as f:
    for line in f:
        last, first, ids = line.split(", ")
        roster[ids.strip()] = ' '.join([first, last])

print(roster)
```

Comment: Why do you use the method call to `readlines()`? A file is iterable, so `for line in f:` is enough.

Answer (score 1):

You are close. However, you don't need a second loop. You can add all the names inside the first one.

```
roster = {}
input_file = open("cs371598roster", "r")
whole_thing = input_file.read()
lines = whole_thing.split("\n")

for line in lines:
    last, first, ids = line.split(", ")
    roster[ids] = first + last

print(roster)
```

Your earlier solution was breaking down your names and ids of the LAST line into single characters and adding those, probably not what you wanted.